# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Can anyone tell me the solution to this?
Below I have mentioned web.php, Domaincontroller.php and HTML form.
Please tell me did I make a mistake in it.

web.php

```
Route::get('/domains','Domaincontroller@ShowDomains');
Route::post('/add_domain','Domaincontroller@AddNewDomain');
```

Domaincontroller.php

```
public function AddNewDomain(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'domain_name' => 'required',
        'domain_register_date' => 'required',
        'domain_expiry_date' => 'required',
        'domain_registrar' => 'required',
        'registrar_username' => 'required',
        'registrar_password' => 'required',
        'registrar_email' => 'required'

    ]);
    
    $domain = new Domain([
        'domain_name' => $request->get('domain_name'),
        'domain_register_date' => $request->get('domain_register_date'),
        'domain_expiry_date' => $request->get('domain_expiry_date'),
        'domain_registrar'  =>$request->get('domain_registrar'),
        'registrar_username' => $request->get('registrar_username'),
        'registrar_password' => $request->get('registrar_password'),
        'registrar_email' => $request->get('registrar_email')
    ]);

    $domain->save();

    return redirect()->route('domain.add_domain')->with('Domain has been added.');
   

}

}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/')}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: Form action is pointing to root route. I'm guessing it should be `add_domain`?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, mark as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your form dont send to the right url

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/add_domain')}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: @remi when you get that error, it's on what url ? do you have any sort of redirection in place ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define named routes first:

```php
Route::post('/add_domain','Domaincontroller@AddNewDomain')->name('adddomain');
```

And then reference the route in your form action:

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('adddomain') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Just a little further cleaning, you can just use `@csrf` instead writing the entire input field for the CSRF token:

```php
<form method="post" action="{{ route('adddomain') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    // Your other fields here
</form>
```